# What hadith are shared by all sects?

Tags: hadith, sunnah, uloom-al-hadith, shia-sunni, sects

What hadith do all sects of Islam (Sunnis, Zaydis, Twelvers, Ismailis, Ibadis, etc.) share in common?

Comment: Maybe the answer is nobody knows. But we need a better focus and definition of what you mean by Hadith. Ibadis have their own sources but also know, use sunni sources. Shi'a generally have a different definition of Hadith than sunnis and sometimes attribute quotes known as a Hadith by sunnis to their imams ...

Comment: @Medi1Saif I wasn't aware that there was a difference among the definition of hadith among the sects of Islam.

Comment: @DavirLun  there isn’t. In islamic contexts Everyone always understands “Hadith” to refer to a hadith of the Prophet Muhammad by default. The shia will specify if they refer to a hadith of an infallible imam.